# How to join 2 table on max record but show all records of the first table?

Tags: sql, join, select, subquery, outer-join

Table Order has order numbers, line numbers and amount. There can be multiple lines on the order. Table freight has freight charges for each order.
How to join the two tables so that freight is added to max line of the order table?
So basically freight is added once and not on each line of the order table as with left join.

**OL**

```
Select ol.orderno , ol.ordersuf, ol.lineno_ , ol.amount
from order ol 
where ol.orderno= 12345
```

[[image: Order Table view]

**AD**

```
select ad.orderno, ad.ordersuf , ad.freight
from Freight ad
where ad.orderno =12345
```

[[image: Freight table]

Expected result:

[[image: Expected result]

Comment: type or paste the data, not images.  Don't make use create sample data for you.

Answer (score 0):

Please try something like this:
The syntax of CASE statement might differ depending on your db.

```
SELECT ol.orderno , ol.ordersuf, ol.lineno_ , ol.amount, CASE
    WHEN ol.lineno_ = (SELECT max(sol.lineno_) FROM order sol WHERE sol.orderno = ol.orderno) THEN ad.freight
    ELSE 0
END AS QuantityText FROM order ol INNER JOIN Freight ad WHERE ol.orderno = ad.orderno
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
  a.orderno, 
  a.ordersuf, 
  a.lineno_, 
  a.amount, 
  CASE WHEN a.lineno_ = Max(a.lineno_) OVER(partition BY a.orderno) THEN b.freight ELSE 0 END AS freight 
FROM 
  ol a 
  INNER JOIN freight b ON a.orderno = b.orderno
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.